Can the partial derivative of a multivariable function be such that it does not depend on the other variable?
I wanted to know if there is a multivariable function out there which when partially differentiated with respect to x returns a function only in x.(Not dependent on y(the other variable)).
For example-
F(x,y) = 2(x^2)y + xy
When differentiated partially w.r.t. x returns
G(x,y) = 4xy + y
We can see that g depends on x and y both but I wanted to find a function which is such that when we differentiate it w.r.t x, it returns in function in x only(not depending on y)
If such a function does not exist, then is there a function which when partially differentiated w.r.t. x gives out a function which has atleast one of its terms not dependent on y. Here term means individual
parts which are seperated by addition. For Example - 4xy and y in G(x,y)

This was my first question, please don't be too harsh while upvoting or downvoting

This question is a duplicate of: Find all the functions f: $\mathbb R^{2}\to \mathbb R$, where $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y\partial x}=0$. Found using Approach0.

@AnneBauval thank you for your response. I was unable to find this.

Yes, such functions exist, and they take the form $f(x,y)=g(x)+h(y)$. Which is to say, you can separate the function into two parts, one part is purely a function of $x$, the other purely a function of $y$, and then you add the two parts.
For instance
$$
f(x,y)=3x^2-e^x+5y^4-\pi\sqrt[3]{y^9-5}
$$

That makes sense. Also is there a function which cannot be separated into seperate function and still holds this property?

@Aditya No, as Arthur wrote, and as proved in the linked post.
